# Adobe inDesign - problems with accented characters when exporting to pdf

Tags: adobe-indesign

While exporting a .indd file to a pdf with inDesign CC 2015 on Mac, most of the accented characters disappear from the output .pdf file created. 
They do not appear and are replaced with blank spaces.

I am using the font Avenir, though i don't think the issue comes from there since the output is the same with a classic font such as Arial or Helvetica.
I've tried many different exports settings, without success.

What drives me crazy is that there is only one single line in my pdf which shows correctly with all the accents. The others do not, although they are perfectly similar, and when i copy and paste the text or whole bloc text from this correct line to the others, the problem still appears.

Comment: Do they display correctly in ID before exporting? Have you checked the font outside ID, in AI or PS?

Comment: Have you tried to open the pdf in different viewers? Mac's "Preview" is known to have many issues: Text can dissapear, white objects can disappear, Pantone colors shows as black etc. I never trust it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like font corruption to me. I would suggest replacing the font from known good files and maybe running a permissions repair.

Two suggestions though:

1) Open the offending PDF in Acrobat Pro, use the text tool and highlight the offending line, hit command-i to get information on the font in the document. hit the Text tab and look at the content there to see if the Embed Permissions are allowable. Also look at Document Properties under the File menu and the fonts tab there to see the list and status of your embedded (or unembedded) fonts. This might give you some useful information on what's happening in the PDF.

2) As a quick fix, back in Acrobat, choose the Edit Object arrow (Under View/Tools/Content), hit the offending line and right click to pull up the contextual menu. Select Edit object. The line should open in Illustrator. Highlight the line and make sure it looks correct with the right font and characters. Use the Create Outlines command from the Type menu to render the font to outlines. Hit save and close the document. Move back to you PDF, the edit should have taken place and replaced the font with the outlined object.

I know that doesn't solve the core issue, but at least it might help you fix the immediate problem. Check your kerning and tracking metrics on the font though. Sometimes editing in Illustrator and outlining can create issues with spacing if you replace the existing characters with another font (obviously) or the same font.